# Best way to import bulk data into ArangoDB

Tags: graph, arangodb, pyarango

I'm currently working on an ArangoDB POC. I find that the time taken for document creation is very high in ArangoDB with PyArango. It takes about 5 minutes to insert 300 documents. I've pasted the rough code below, please let me know if there are better ways to speed this up :

```
with open('abc.csv') as fp:
for line in fp:
    dataList = line.split(",")

    aaa = dbObj['aaa'].createDocument()
    bbb = dbObj['bbb'].createDocument() 
    ccc = dbObj['ccc'].createEdge()

    bbb['bbb'] = dataList[1]
    aaa['aaa'] = dataList[0]
    aaa._key = dataList[0]

    aaa.save()
    bbb.save()

    ccc.links(aaa,bbb)
    ccc['related_to'] = "gfdgf"
    ccc['weight'] = 0

    ccc.save()
```

The different collections are created by the below code :

```
 dbObj.createCollection(className='aaa', waitForSync=False)
```

Comment: Did you consider [arangoimp](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.0/Manual/Administration/Arangoimp.html)? If necessary, you can pre-process your source data with Python, but the import itself should be done by arangoimp, which uses ArangoDB's bulk import API for efficiency.

Comment: I looked into the arangoimp, It looks like the data should be in the form of JSON, CSV files with already present primary keys. The problem i see here is i'll not be able to handle duplicate nodes, which might be already present in the DB. Are there any specific options to handle these conditions, i couldn't find any in the ArangoImp documentation

Comment: pyArango currently has a problem with HTTP `keep-alive` - it won't reuse connections and thus eventually re-do DNS lookups. We're currently investigating what could be the cause of this and how to fix it.

Comment: @dothebart : Thanks for the information. I recently tried with java driver for ArangoDB, with the batch mode enabled it transferred data at rates of about 1000 documents/ second, however the edge collections are not getting updated in it. The same code updated the Edge collections once i removed the batch mode. Please can you let me know if you have any ideas on this.

Comment: @pjesudhas: arangoimp supports JSON, CSV and TSV. A document key does not need to be present. If you leave it out, ArangoDB will generate a key for you. You do need the `_from` and `_to` attributes for edges of course, to tell it which documents to link. This is done using document IDs (`_id`, collection name + "/" + document key). The documents you want to link do not actually have to exist, only the collection must be present. For how to handle duplicate documents, see here: https://docs.arangodb.com/3.0/Manual/Administration/Arangoimp.html#updating-existing-documents

Comment: @CoDEmanX : Thanks for the info, i'll follow this procedure

Comment: meanwhile pyArango has been fixed - it will now successfully use http connection keepalive again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for your problem with the batch mode in the arango java driver. if you know the key attributes of the vertices you can build the document handle by "collectionName" + "/" + "documentKey".
Example:

```
arangoDriver.startBatchMode();

for(String line : lines)
{
  String[] data = line.split(",");

  BaseDocument device = new BaseDocument();
  BaseDocument phyAddress = new BaseDocument(); 
  BaseDocument conn = new BaseDocument();

  String keyDevice = data[0];
  String handleDevice = "DeviceId/" + keyDevice; 

  device.setDocumentKey(keyDevice);

  device.addAttribute("device_id",data[0]);

  String keyPhyAddress = data[1];
  String handlePhyAddress = "PhysicalLocation/" + keyPhyAddress; 

  phyAddress.setDocumentKey(keyPhyAddress);

  phyAddress.addAttribute("address",data[1]);

  final DocumentEntity<BaseDocument> from = arangoDriver.graphCreateVertex("testGraph", "DeviceId", device, null);       
  final DocumentEntity<BaseDocument> to = arangoDriver.graphCreateVertex("testGraph", "PhysicalLocation", phyAddress, null);

  arangoDriver.graphCreateEdge("testGraph", "DeviceId_PhysicalLocation", null, handleDevice, handlePhyAddress, null, null);

}
arangoDriver.executeBatch();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would build all of the data to be inserted into a json formatted string and use createDocumentRaw to create them all at once with one save.